# How to avoid overwriting of k, v in dictionaries

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, for-loop

My program is parsing values from an XML file and then puts them into a dictionary.

Here I've used a for loop to iterate all tags from the file and attributes and also the text

But when there is a subtag like `[250][155]` which is `<name>`, it will overwrite the `[4]` `<name>`

And all of this is running under the for loop

Now, I want to hinder the loop from overwriting the values once it has been entered into the loop

```
import pprint as p  # Importing pprint/pretty print for formatting dict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETT  # Importing xml.etree for xml parsing
import csv  # Importing csv to write in CSV file


def fetch_data():
    # Asking input from user for the file path
    xml_file_path = input(
        "Enter the path to the file. \n Note* use 'Double back slash' instead of 'single back slash': \n \t \t \t \t \t")

    # Initiating variable parser which will parse from the file
    parser = ETT.parse(xml_file_path)

    # Initiating variable root to get root element which will be useful in further queries
    root = parser.getroot()

    # Initiating variable main_d which is the dictionary in which the parsed data will be stored
    main_d = {}

    for w in root.iter():  # Making a for loop which will iter all tags out of the file
        value = w.attrib  # Initiating variable value for storing attributes where attributes are in the form of dictionaries
        value['value'] = w.text  # Hence, appending the text/value of the tag in the value dict
        if w not in main_d:
            main_d[w.tag] = value  # Writing all the keys and values in main_d
        else:
            main_d.pop(w)
    p.pprint(main_d, sort_dicts=False, width=200, depth=100)


fetch_data()
```

This is what the XML would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data data_version="1">
    <modified_on_date>some_time</modified_on_date>
    <file_version>some version</file_version>
    <name>h</name>
    <class>Hot</class>
    <fct>
        <fc_tem di="value1" un="value2" unn="value3">some integer</fc_tem>
        <fc_str di="value1" un="value2" unn="value3">some integer</fc_str>
        <DataTable name="namee" type="0" columns="2" rows="2" version="some version">
            <name>this will be overwritten on the first one up there</name>
            <type>0</type>
        </DataTable>    
    </fct>
</Data>
```

This is my progress so far

Taking into account the confidentiality of the program, that's all I can share

Comment: Could you edit the question to include this?

Comment: sure, gimme a min

Comment: `if w not in main_d` - your keys into `main_d`  are `main_d[ w.tag ] = ...` not `w` - how could there ever be a key thats `w` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, doesn't work.

Did u mean like this or something else?

        if main_d.keys() not in main_d:
            main_d[w.tag] = value                       # Writing all the keys and values in main_d
        else:
            main_d.pop(w)

Comment: It's completely unclear what your program is supposed to do based on this XML sample. What kind of data structure are you trying to create - and more importantly - *why*? The XML tree already is a neatly nested (and easily searchable!) data structure. It's probably not necessary to build a dict from it.

Comment: I mean that the only way things go into your dict is by `main_d[w.tag] = value` .- so the KEY to your dict is `w.tag`.  You test `if w not in main_d:` - `w` is _obviously_ different from `w.tag` that you use as key. There will never be any `w` as key in your dict. `main_d.pop(w)` will also never work. Also: Why let the user input double backslashes? If you (on the prompt) input 'c:\a\b\c.txt' you do not need to double up on `\` because input does not care - you cannot input `\t` and get a 0x10 in your data. Did you test any of this?

Comment: @Tomalak . For this purpose even I am unclear as my seniors told me to work on this. 

Yes the  XML itself is very beautiful but this is the sample one and the real one  has nearly 38K  lines of  data or tags  from which most  are repetitive  and it has to be  entered  in a  .csv  file  lateron  opened in  Excel

Comment: Okay, so show the CSV you expect to create from the sample XML file (edit your question, add matching sample output, describe which data goes where).

Comment: @PatrickArtner .  Okay boss I'll change the input statement, and yes my senior reviewed the code and said the pop() will cause havoc

Comment: @Tomalak . Yes I'll edit it ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @PatrickArtner, his way worked

so you just have to do w.tag instead of w

the full snippet is:

```
# This program is to fetch/parse data(tags, attribs, text) from the XML/XMT
# file provided


# Importing required libraries

import pprint as p                                      # Importing pprint/pretty print for formatting dict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETT                     # Importing xml.etree for xml parsing
import csv                                              # Importing csv to write in CSV file


# Creating a method/function fetch_data() to fetch/parse data from the given XML/XMT file

def fetch_data():


    # Asking input from user for the file path
    xml_file_path = input(
        "Enter the path to the file \n \t \t :")

    # Asking input from user for the name of the csv file which will be created
    file_name = input(str("Enter the file name with extension you want as output \n \t \t : "))


    # Initiating variable parser which will parse from the file
    parser = ETT.parse(xml_file_path)


    # Initiating variable root to get root element which will be useful in further queries
    root = parser.getroot()


    # Initiating variable main_d which is the dictionary in which the parsed data will be stored
    main_d = {}


    for w in root.iter():                               # Making a for loop which will iter all tags out of the file
        value = w.attrib                                # Initiating variable value for storing attributes where attributes are in the form of dictionaries
        value['value'] = w.text                         # Hence, appending the text/value of the tag in the value dict
        if w.tag not in main_d:                         # Checking if the tag exists or not, this will help to avoid overwriting of tag values
            main_d[w.tag] = value                       # Writing all the keys and values in main_d
        else:
            pass

    p.pprint(main_d, sort_dicts=False, width=200)               # This is just to check the output

    with open(file_name, 'w+', buffering=True) as file:         # Opening a file with the filename provided by the user
        csvwriter = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)     # Initiating a variable csvwriter for the file and passing QUOTE_ALL agr.
        for x in main_d.keys():                                 # Creating a loop to write the tags
            csvwriter.writerow({x})                             # Writing the tags



fetch_data()
```